# Reemplazar parte de un string en una columna entera

Tags: sql, sql-server

mi consulta es la siguiente:

Tengo una columna con correos del estilo "correo@ejemplo.com" y quiero substituir todos los registros que tengan el dominio "@ejemplo.com" por "@ejemplo.es".

Por lo tanto si antes teníamos estos datos

```
correo1@ejemplo.com
correo2@mantener.com 
correo3@ejemplo.com
```

Ahora deberían quedar así:

```
correo1@ejemplo.es  
correo2@mantener.com
correo3@ejemplo.es
```

¿Alguien sabe si es posible? 
PD: No me sirve hacer un REPLACE porque según he estado viendo guarda los registros en otra tabla.

Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: REPLACE sí te sirve, lo que necesitas es hacer un UPDATE en vez de un INSERT. REPLACE no guarda valores solo los cambia.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español, te recomiendo que mires [ask] para realizar una buena pregunta, debes añadir las pruebas y lo que hayas investigado para poder ayudarte mejor. De paso puedes pasarte por el [tour] y así obtendrás tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si puedes utilizar `replace`, en una sentencia `update`, para actualizar el mismo campo de la tabla, por ejemplo:

```
create table #prueba (
  correo nvarchar(300)
);

insert into #prueba
values ('correo1@ejemplo.com correo2@mantener.com correo3@ejemplo.com')
     , ('correo7@ejemplo.com');

update #prueba
   set correo = replace(correo, '@ejemplo.com', '@ejemplo.es');

select *
  from #prueba;
```

Nos devuelve esto:

```
correo
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
correo1@ejemplo.es correo2@mantener.com correo3@ejemplo.es
correo7@ejemplo.es

(2 rows affected)
```

Comment: Tal vez sería bueno notar que si existe un `@ejemplo.com.mx` se convertiría en `@ejemplo.es.mx`. Y que es bueno respaldar la información antes de hacer cambios de este estilo.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte! Por si alguien lee esto y tiene el mismo problema al hacer el REPLACE, yo lo he solucionado añadiendo un where para que el replace se ejecute unicamente en aquellos campos que debe de modificar. Tal que así:
update GDSC_0016_BUZON
   set BUZON = replace(BUZON, '@ejemplo.com', '@ejemplo.es') WHERE BUZON LIKE '%@ejemplo.com';

Comment: Hola, la pregunta original mostraba varios buzones en una sola línea. Eso complicaba un poco las cosas. Si hay un solo buzón por línea, el `where` es pertinente y de hecho, prevendrá lo anotado por Luis en el comentario anterior.